# git change intermediate commit without changing later one

Tags: git, rebase

This happens to me occasionally (well, maybe frequently):

**Note**: All of the following happens before I push.

My software project needs a new feature.
I code and test until it works.
I had had to make room for the new feature, so I divide the changes into two commits using `git add -i`:

```
A --- R --- F
```

Commit `R` introduces the refactoring changes, `F` adds the code for the new feature.

Now I realise that I made mistakes in dividing the changes, so some that are in `F` actually belong to `R` already, and vice versa.
So, basically, `R` is messed up and doesn't pass the tests (whereas the final state of `F` is perfect).

To fix that, I check out `R` on a temporary branch and fix everything.
I `git commit --amend` and now I have

```
A --- R --- F
  \
   \-- R'
```

So all that is missing now is moving `F` to the new branch.
So far, my solution was to do `git rebase --onto R-prime R F` (I actually use the branch names, but you see what I mean).
The problem with that is that it's not exactly what I want: `git` understands I want to move the *changes* between `R` and `F` onto `R'`, giving me a commit `F'` that might be different from `F`.
However, I want `F'` to be exactly the same as `F`, except for its ancestor.
Frequently, the `rebase` causes conflicts which are tricky to fix (i.e. error-prone).

Is there a way to tell `git` that I want to move the *snapshot* of `F`, not the diff `R`→`F`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your current HEAD is at `R'`, it should be like (substitute hashes instead of `F` and `R'`)

```
git reset --hard F
git reset --soft R'
git commit -c F
```

It takes the tree from `F` as is, and commits it as child of `R'`, substituting commit message from `F` and invoking editor it you would like to change it

Comment: I understand what is happening, but it's not something I'd do before going to bed at midnight... Thanks anyway!